# How to show the week number on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I show the week number on Google Calendar?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, so in the left part of your view, click on the
***Other Calendars->Add->Browse Interesting Calendars->More->Week numbers***

Comment: oh thanks a lot! very nice, I didn't known that feature. It can be added also national holidays and birthday wow

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Janis. This is a perfect solution for mondays.  But for people their workweek starts on sundays, here is better solution: https://sites.google.com/site/gcalweeknumbers/ (Using Ctrl-F, Search for the word sundays and click the link). Also the above-linked page has better icon style, with more contrast, which might be useful for people whose calendar starts on mondays as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have changed recently. I found that if you go to Settings > General > Language and region and then scroll down to "View options" you can select "Show Week Numbers"
[image: View of settings screen in google calendar]